# Cannot connect to exim4 SMTP server

Tags: firewall, smtp, tcp, tcpdump

I have the problem that I cannot connect to my exim4 SMTP server from my home network:

```
$ telnet -4 example.com 25
Trying 1.2.3.4...
telnet: connect to address 1.2.3.4: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

`netstat` on the server tells me that exim4 is listening on port 25, both IPv4 and IPv6. I started `tcpdump` on my server to check whether the request reaches the server, it shows nothing. I was puzzled and, as a last test, deleted all `iptables` rules as described [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-iptables-stop/). Still, I am getting the *Connection refused* error.

Wireshark tells me that the server responds to my telnet request with RST/ACK, which implies that the port is closed. However, if I connect to the server from anywhere but my home network, it works without problems.

I have checked that the request leaves my local gateway and it does.

So now I am out of ideas. What could possibly lead to this request being rejected? Since `tcpdump` does not show anything and I get a RST/ACK, it must be at a very low level, but I cannot imagine what beyond iptables could block the incoming request – especially since this only seems to occur for packages from my home IP.

Comment: Don't tell us what you see, *show* us what you see.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check that the host on the other side is pingable.
When you do that try to ping it and set up

```
tcpdump -ni any icmp
```

on the Exim server.

You should be able to confirm that the pings are traversing properly, and that the address in the iptables on the server side is correct.

If you have any other services on the Exim server then try to telnet to those too, like in example HTTP on port 80, or something similiar.
When that succeeds you will know that you are getting closer, if it doesn't then double check the firewall rules and that they are inserted **BEFORE** the **DROP** (actually **REJECT** in this case as the telnet says) rules, otherwise they will never have a chance to work.

To put a rule in the iptables at 0 position use the

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -s 5.6.7.8 -j ACCEPT
```

instead of

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -s 5.6.7.8 -j ACCEPT
```

where the **5.6.7.8** should be the address that you saw on tcpdump with ICMP packets or any kind of whatsmyip site.

If other services work and the port 25 still doesn't then be aware that some **ISP's** block the tcp port 25 deliberately to reduce spam on the network, therefore you might be forced to either :

- contact your ISP and request a ban lift from that port from your IP
- configure Exim to work also on another port (I suggest port 465 with encryption, but unencrypted port 587 is very commonly used to circumvent such firewalls)
- use VPN to set up a tunnel to the Exim server and route traffic through it

Comment: other services (HTTP(S), IMAP, SSH) work properly and I can ping the server with proper IP. I will try and contact my ISP.

Comment: You might also check your IP address in online RBL check tools. It might be the case that the class of your ISP is on a blocklist and the datacenter is filtering the incoming network connections from blocked IP ranges.